# Inserting column data from another table together with more value

Tags: sql

How to insert few columns from TableA to tableB together with some additional values. 
Following is one way I tried and failed, but it shows clearly what I want to achive:

```
Insert into 
TableA (UserID, FirstName, Lastname,EmailAddress,IsActive,IsOnline,IsLockedOut,Comment) 
values 
(Select distinct UserID, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress from TableB,0,0,0,'Imported')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the hard code values along with the columns before the `FROM` part of your query. SO, change your query to this:

```
Select distinct UserID, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, 0, 0, 0, 'Imported'
from TableB
```

Comment: I tried this and failed first. I tried it now without 'SYSDATETIME' inside values and it worked. Any idea how to insert SYSDATETIME along with others.

Comment: Should be `SYSDATETIME()` since it is a function.

Comment: okey , got it used it as CONVERT(DateTime, CONVERT(Varchar(11),GetDate(), 106)) as sdate. that worked.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `values` when you use `select` keyword, also you should include constant/static values in your `select` statement itself, try this

```
Insert into 
TableA 
(
UserID, FirstName, Lastname,
EmailAddress,IsActive,IsOnline,
IsLockedOut,Comment
) 
Select distinct UserID, FirstName, LastName, 
EmailAddress ,
0,0,0,'Imported'
FROM TableB
```